# How to turn images into thumbnail size using foreach loop in Wordpress Pods CMS

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails, image-size, podscms

I am using Wordpress Pods CMS and I have a foreach loop to show an unordered list of images.
I would like to turn the images into thumbnail size (using the WordPress media thumbnail settings in the dashboard).

My code currently look like this...

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($thePod->get_field('images') as $photo) {
  echo "<li><img src=\"{$photo['guid']}\" alt=\"{$name}\" /></li>";
}
?>
      <?php else:?>
      <p>no photos</p>
      <?php endif;?>
</ul>
```

I tried putting .... "{$photo['guid'], 'thumbnail'}" but that doesn't work and I know this usually works ... "wp_get_attachment_image_src($image['0']['id'], 'thumbnail');" when I want to display one image only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($thePod->get_field('images') as $photo) {
  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $photo[ID], 'thumbnail' );
  echo "<li><img src='$thumbnail[0]' alt='$name' /></li>";
}
```

mkm

Comment: thanks @manishie for your reply. How would I apply that to my current code? I see this person has it inside his image tag.. 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/slideshowpro-038-wordpress..
is it similar to this? and also what if I have other image format too like png or image extension is jpeg as well as jpg.

Comment: Sandy, rather than the quick hack I gave you before, I've revised my answer to figure out what you may have been doing incorrectly in your code.  Please see if it works for you...

Comment: You'll want to use $thePod->field( 'images' ) instead http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/field/